# How to return a value inside or outside a Spring Webflux Mono Subscribe depending on specific test result inside the subscribe

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux

I'm a beginner in Spring Web flux and in java Stream.
I need to call a method that returns a Mono twice depending on the result content of the first call.
But I don't know how to make it works and how to respect best practices i.e not to have 2 return statements in my method.

Off course the code below does not work but I want to show the kind of behaviour that I would like to have. But Don't know how to have it in a Stream way...

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Compare {


    @Autowired
    Myservice myService;
    
    
    public Mono<MyResponse> compute(String firstItem,String secondItem, String thirdItem){
        
        // First Comparison between firstItem and secondItem
        Mono<MyResponse> firstResponse = myService.sendRequestToCompare(firstItem,secondItem);
        

        firstResponse.subscribe(result -> { // Issue on the subscribe method according to my IDE
            
            if ((result.getResponse().getStatus().toString() == "NOT_SAME") && (result.getResponse().getErrorCode() == 201)) {
            
            // Second Comparison with a third value if the previous first one does not match
            Mono<MyResponse> secondResponse = myService.sendRequestToCompare(firstItem,thirdItem);          
                return secondResponse; // Error raised in IDE says change to return; or change method retrun type to Mono<MyResponse> which is already the case
                break;              
            }
        }, error -> {
            log.error("The following error happened on getResponse method from myService!", error);
        });
        return firstResponse;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you going to get thirdItem from? Is it result of sendRequestToCompare(firstItem,secondItem), i.e. firstResponse result?

Comment: please also (little) dive into https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/592355 (and why `String x == String y` can work out 9 of 10 times, but won't the other time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no use and need of `java.util.stream.*` (though they can co-exist/interact, no need to complicate), but here a (sample, `String`) version of your method:

```java
public Mono<String> compute(String first, String second, String third) {
    Mono<String> firstResponse = 
        // just demo, call real service instead:
        Mono.just(first);
    return firstResponse.flatMap(s -> { // !
        if (s.equals("Hello")) { // some (demo) condition
            Mono<String> secondResponse = 
                // just demo, call real service instead:
                Mono.just(s + second + third);
            return secondResponse;
        } else {
            return Mono.just(";("); // Mono.empty()/throw exception/...
        }
    });
}
```

It:

1. returns `secondResponse`, when the item emitted by `firstResponse` equals to `"Hello"` (i.e. meets some condition)
2. otherwise a `Mono` (i.e. "publisher") of `";("` (sad emoji:)

(without comments and (demo) variables, it is a "one-liner";)

This how an according (junit5, reactor) test can look like:

```java
@Test
void testMyCompute() {
    testee.compute("Hello", " World", "!")
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectNext("Hello World!")
            .verifyComplete();

    testee.compute("", "", "")
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectNext(";(")
            .verifyComplete();

    NullPointerException npe = assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,() -> testee.compute(null, null, null));
    assertNotNull(npe);
}
```

So most attention on [`flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operator.

> Transform the item emitted by this Mono *asynchronously*, returning <s>the value *emitted by*</s> another Mono

(In opposite to [`map`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operator, which does the same *synchronously*, returning *the value* (not a Mono/Publisher) ..e.g. when `secondResponse` would be "blocking"/`String` not `Mono<String>`)

Useful Links:

- [Core Reference Doc(#which-operator?)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator)
- [Testing Reference Doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#testing)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to call `Mono.flatMap()`. It requires as an argument a function from the first Mono **result** to another Mono **object** and returns Mono. If you are looking for chain of calls (call service A, then service B and get service B response) - that's a typical case for the `Mono.flatMap()`.